# Propagate=False in BIML

Tags: ssis, biml

I'm using BIML to create my package.

There is a sequence container where I want to set the system variable **Propagate** to False. 
I cannot find the method in BIML to set the system variable for Propagate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propagate is a System scoped variable that only exists within Event Handlers.

The following Biml creates an SSIS Package with an OnError event handler that has an empty Sequence Container

The Event itself redefines the System::Propagate variable to have a value of `false` instead of the default value of `true`

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_38121956">
            <Events>
                <Event EventType="OnError" Name="OnError">
                    <Variables>
                        <Variable DataType="Boolean" Name="Propagate" Namespace="System">false</Variable>
                    </Variables>
                    <Tasks>
                        <Container Name="SEQC Propagate no more">
                        </Container>
                    </Tasks>
                </Event>
            </Events>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using BIML Online.

http://bimlonline.com/

Here you can upload an existing SSIS package with propagate set and the browser based application will reverse engineer it for you to give you the BIML.

Its handy if you know how to do something in SSIS, but not sure of the BIML equivalent.

Officially its still in Beta, but works well.

Comment: Thank this will help me for future syntax search of BIML :)

Comment: This reverse engineering functionality has since been added to the BIMLExpress extension for SSDT, where you can right click on a package (or packages) in SSDT and Select "Convert SSIS Packages to BIML"